# System.IO.File.Exists(fpath) returns false in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code which works in Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox and Google Chrome.

```
public ActionResult LogoForm(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        string fpath = file.FileName;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fpath))
        {
            // Logic comes here
        }
    }
}
```

In my View I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogoForm", "LogoEditor", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <text>Logo Image &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <text> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</text>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
}
```

In case of any file in Firefox and Chrome, the line 'if (System.IO.File.Exists(fpath))' always returns false! It doesn't find the file. Why so?

Comment: What do you get if you display the value of `fpath`?

Comment: There is a file.FullName ? use that instead.

Comment: Well, I had noticed that in IE 'file.FileName' it returns the full file path, like 'C:\\My Documents\\..' whereas in Chrome and Firefox it returns just "Blue Hills.jpg". Is there any other better way to check if the file exists on the client machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file.FileName` contains the file path **on the client** computer, not on the server. You should not use it on the server. The reason this works in IE is because IE happens to send the full path to the file to the server and since you are running both the client and the server on the same machine it works. Chrome and FF for security reasons never send the file path. IIRC they send a dummy path to the server that doesn't exist anywhere. This won't work with IE neither when you deploy your application in IIS and access it remotely.

You should never rely on the path portion of `file.FileName`. You should only extract the filename and then concatenate it with some path **on the server**:

Like for example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogoForm(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        string path = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), path);
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        { 
            // logic comes here
        }
    }
}
```

I would also recommend you checking out the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) about uploading files in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

When you say it returns false "in" Chrome and Firefox - it's not the browser executing your code, of course. It's the server executing code in response to a request.

Presumably they're giving the filename in some different format to IE. You should log what `file.FileName` is, and that should make it clearer what's going on. It's slightly alarming to see that you're just taking the *exact* filename posted by the browser - in the case of a relative filename it's probably not relative to the directory you want, and in the case of an absolute filename you're comparing whether a file that exists on the *client* computer exists in the same place on the *server* - which again, isn't a good idea.

EDIT: It sounds like you're interested in whether or not the file really exists on the client computer. Two points:

- You can't tell, and `File.Exists` *certainly* isn't the right check. That's running on the *server* which doesn't have access to the client's file system, thank goodness.
- You shouldn't care. Maybe the client doesn't really *have* a local file system - maybe it's simulating it from some cloud storage, or something like that. You're not meant to care about that: you've been given a request with some information about a "file upload" and *that's* what you should care about.

Comment: Well, I had noticed that in IE 'file.FileName' it returns the full file path, like 'C:\\My Documents\\..' whereas in Chrome and Firefox it returns just "Blue Hills.jpg". Is there any other better way to check if the file exists on the client machine?

Comment: @karank: Well you shouldn't be using `File.Exists` to start with! That's checking on the *server*. If they've made a file upload request, then what difference does it matter whether their purported filename actually exists?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer posts the original filename including the path for a type="file" input control, whereas other browsers just deliver the filename.

Since the browser usually does not run on the server, why do you want to check whether the full filename exists on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to use the path of what was sent into the controller (as others have mentioned, supported locally by Internet Explorer only), try the following:

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
{
    // The fielname
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

    // Store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder for example
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);

     // Other stuff    
}
```

Comment: Did you mean something else other than 'Rather than using `System.IO`' seeing that in your example  `Path` exists in the System.IO namespace?

Comment: Thanks Anthony, apparently had a brain fart part way through typing that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what people have already said, if the user has added the file to the file input control, it must exist on the client's computer somewhere, since they've added it to the form on the website.

Once they've clicked submit, the HttpPostedFileBase inputstream property contains the bytes of the file, the filename is simply given so that you know what the name of the file is that was uploaded. As others have suggested use Path.GetFilename(string) to retrieve only the filename without directory path (if provided) and save that to your server. Generally, I will append some sort of timestamp to the file as to not overwrite a previous upload