# Don't Want to Download the Specified File if Not Exist on Website

Tags: c#, winforms

i faced an issue with downloading file from website.

A user can fill in the textbox (example: hello.html) and then click on a button to download the html file. Now my issue is: even the file "hello.html" is not exists, my code will tend to download it as well. There will be "index.html" file appears in folder. How do I write "if" statement so that I can tell the code not to download if the file is not exist?

My code:

```
if (FILE NOT EXIST ON THE WEBSITE)
         {
              //MessageBox.Show("There is no such file on the website. Please check your spelling.");             
         }
         else
         {
              client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/" + txtbox.Text.ToUpper().ToString(),
                                                sourceDir + txtbox.Text.ToUpper().ToString() + ".html");
         }
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.IO.File.Exists(fpath) returns false in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295164/system-io-file-existsfpath-returns-false-in-chrome-firefox)

```
if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
{ 
    // Download File!
}
```

That problem is specific for uploading but its the same concept.

OR:

Taken Directly from: http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-check-remote-file-exists-using-c/

Add this method to your class.

```
private bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
    try
    {
        //Creating the HttpWebRequest
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        //Getting the Web Response.
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        //Returns TURE if the Status code == 200
        return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch
    {
        //Any exception will returns false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then when you want to check if a file exists at a url use this:

```
if (RemoteFileExists("http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png")
{
    //File Exists
}
else
{
    //File does not Exist
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure its the same? You have to use `Server.MapPath()` though. If not you could always use this: http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-check-remote-file-exists-using-c/

Comment: thanks for pointing out the link. :D will try it out and update you!

Comment: i can't make it work. as I just learn programming since 2 months ago, i am totally lost. D:

Comment: @Shyuan you have to provide specifics.. Do you get an error? Does it crash? A bug?

Comment: Hi Nate, appreciate your help. It doesn't work in the way I wanted as I have quite a few nested "if" statements. I put this particular "if" statement at the wrong place perhaps. I hope there's other way to discuss about this rather than pasting my code here. It's quite a big piece. Supposed if the file is not found, it will say file not found. And, if the file is found, it will do the code, but it tells me file not found too and the file is not downloaded. Not sure where am I doing wrongly. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Nate, this is what exactly I did, but I think I placed the `if (RemoteFileExists("http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png")` at wrong position (as I have quite a number of `if` statement which quite confused me which `if` statement should come first. Thanks for sorting this out for me. I will try placing this particular `if` statement correctly. I appreciate your help :)